# How to get inner array data

Tags: android, listview

I am building an Android app and are collecting data from my remote API (using Volley)
and I need to parse the response. I know how to get the "projects" array but how can I get the title for each project (please note the project key for each project).

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "total": 4,
  "projects": [
    {
      "project": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "A nice long title",
        "latitude": 56.0293783,
        "longitude": 12.7256732,
        "created_at": "2013-10-20T20:57:00+02:00",
        "created_at_human": "5 months",
        "total_tasks": 7,
        "description": "This is a description.",
        "address": "simple highway 22",
        "zipcode": "25656",
        "city": "florida"
      }
    },
    {
      "project": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "A nice long title",
        "latitude": 56.0293783,
        "longitude": 12.7256732,
        "created_at": "2013-10-20T20:57:00+02:00",
        "created_at_human": "5 months",
        "total_tasks": 7,
        "description": "This is a description.",
        "address": "simple highway 22",
        "zipcode": "25656",
        "city": "florida"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the code I use now and that needs to be modified:

```
JSONArray jsonPosts = mData.getJSONArray("projects");

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blogPosts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.e("OUTPUT", "THE POST: " + post);

            }
```

This outputs:

```
E/OUTPUT﹕ THE POST: {"project":{"id":1,"title":"A nice long title","total_tasks":7,"address":"simple highway 22","description":"This is a description.","zipcode":"25656","created_at":"2013-10-20T20:57:00+02:00","longitude":12.7256732,"created_at_human":"5 MåNADER","latitude":56.0293783,"city":"florida"}}
```

How can I access the title for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `jSONObject` item contains a key and `jSONObject`. I think you need to get jSONObject from item in Array then get title and city.

I hope it will helpful for you........

```
JSONArray jsonPosts = mData.getJSONArray("projects");
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blogPosts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject innerjson = post.getJSONObject("project");

                String title = innerjson.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                       title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();

                String city = innerjson.getString(KEY_CITY);
                       city = Html.fromHtml(city).toString();

                HashMap<String, String> blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();

                blogPost.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                blogPost.put(KEY_CITY, city);
                blogPosts.add(blogPost);

            }

            String[] keys = {KEY_TITLE, KEY_CITY};
            int[] ids = { R.id.top_label, R.id.bottom_label};

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, blogPosts, R.layout.list_item, keys, ids);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `JSONArray` and not a `JSONObject` - to make a `JSONObject` from it, use

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

this gets the first JSONObject from this JSONArray.

If you have multiple JSONObjects, use this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject;
for(int n = 0; n < jsonArray.length(); n++)
{
    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(n);
}
```

To get the values:

```
jsonObject.getString("name");
```